# Using Regex to capture sub-string after a word and before another not working

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my template (`html.eex` file) I want to capture the value of a specific CSS property inside a string with several CSS values using a Regex. I think the Regex is correct but I'm getting a syntax error.

For example, to capture the value of the `width` in this string (`40`):

```
A: "height: 35px; width: 40px; margin: 10px",
```

I'm using:

```
<%= Regex.named_captures(~r/(?<=width: ).*?(?=px)/, to_string @A) |> elem(0) %>
```

and I'm getting an argument error.

Comment: I feel like you'd be better off parsing the css, for example a simple parser could be constructed using combine - https://github.com/bitwalker/combine

Comment: @PawełObrok. I didn't know that. It seems like an alternative. I'll look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
Regex.named_captures(~r/width: (?<width>.*)px/U, string)
%{"width" => "40"}
```

the `U` at the end means non greedy, otherwise it returns:

```
Regex.named_captures(~r/width: (?<width>.*)px/, string)
%{"width" => "40px; margin: 10"}
```

Comment: Ok. Now I can grab the value but I'm getting an error: `protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{"width" => "40"}`

Comment: Yes, because it returns map instead of string. You just need to append `["width"]` to extract the value: `Regex.named_captures(~r/width: (?<width>.*)px/U, string)["width"]`

Comment: The `.width` notation is shorthand for `[:width]`, but in this key the key is not atom, but string.

Comment: I've run into a CSS property that does not fit this Regex:` flex: 0 0 470px` where `0`s can be `1`s instead. IS is simple to change our Regex to grab just the number before `px`or do we need a different approach? Thanks.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to just split the result string by spaces and take the last thing: `result |> String.split(" ") |> List.last`. In case of just "40" it will return "40", but in case of "0 0 0 470" it will return "470".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again.